# how to change jqgrid toolbar button tooltips from site master

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, toolbar

How to change jqgrid button tooltip texts at runtime? The following code in Site.Master does not change them, static tooltip texts tooltips are still read only from grid.locale-xx.js file. How to change them in Site.Master ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;

jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.defaults, {

addtitle: 'Add new row new tooltip', 
deltitle: 'delete button new tooltio', 
edittitle: '<%= Res.I("Muuda rida")+" (F4)" %>', 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `jQuery.jgrid.nav` instead of `jQuery.jgrid.defaults`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
    $.jgrid.useJSON = true;

    jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.nav, {
        addtitle: 'Add new row new tooltip',
        deltitle: 'delete button new tooltio',
        edittitle: '<%= Res.I("Muuda rida")+" (F4)" %>',
    });
</script>
```